# Input field "value" attribute truncated after the first space when passing a Flask variable

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, jinja2

I am passing a Jinja2 template variable to an input field's value attribute. The text that I am trying to pass gets chopped off after the first space. For example: If the variable contained "Harley Davidson" the field would be populated with just "Harley". Here is the line from my code. I have tried with and without the double quotes with the same result.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="companyname" name="companyname" value="{{company}}" />
```

There are several questions about this on SOF but none specifically relating to Flask (that I could find).

Comment: can you crosscheck if variable company  really contains Harley Davidson, can you show any image of what is happening

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure of the text content, then try `value="{{company|safe}}"` . See [documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/?highlight=safe#jinja-filters.safe)